# Android App linking: Android app linking doesn't work in release or cert build variant

Tags: android, universal-link

I am implementing app linking feature in my app. I am getting one weird issue where its working with debug build but not in release or cert build. Have anyone faced this issue before.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you state the hash fingerprint of your release keystore certificate in the `assetlinks.json` or did you use the key from your debug key?

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Yes the SHA256 certificate is uploaded to respective domain to specific location(.well-known/assetlinks.json).
Its also success in https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator. Not sure why its not working in the generated build